# How to search by using group by clause for two or more fields using sunspot solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, mysql2, sunspot-rails

Please any one tell me is it possible put conditions on the associated fields using sunspot solr. I have four models. That is brands, departments, categories and product_details. brands table contains id, name and verified (flag). departments contains id, name. categories contains id and name. product_details contains name, price, image_url, discount, brand_id, department id and category_id.

brand.rb

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_details, :dependent=>:destroy
end
```

department.rb

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_details, :dependent=>:destroy
end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_details, :dependent=>:destroy
end
```

product_detail.rb

```
class ProductDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :id
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :brand
  searchable do
    text :name
    text :brand do
      brand.name
    end
    integer :department_id
    integer :category_id
    integer :brand_id
    string :department_id_str do
      department_id.to_s
    end
    string :category_id_str do
      category_id.to_s
    end
    string :brand_id_str do
      brand_id.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

product_details_controller.rb

```
def index
    @idproducts=ProductDetail.search do
        group :category_id_str, :brand_id_str, :department_id_str
    end
end
```

In product_details/index.html.erb

```
<% @idproducts.group(:category_id_str,:brand_id_str,:department_id_str).groups.each do |group| %>
    <% group.results.each do |result| %>
        <%= debug(result)%>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

For the above code am getting wrong number of arguments (3 for 1) error

```
<% @idproducts.group([:category_id_str,:brand_id_str,:department_id_str]).groups.each do |group| %>
    <% group.results.each do |result| %>
        <%= debug(result)%>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

For the above code am getting undefined method `to_sym' for #<Array:0x8a14ebc> error.

I have observed multi column grouping in controller is successfull. But am getting to display the result. Please any one tell me how to display the multi column grouping result.

Please help I have strucked in above mentioned problems.